# Convert string in to the DateTimeoffset in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, biztalk, psql, biztalk-2013

I am trying to pull data from the psql database and insert them into the SQL Server database using BizTalk. There is a column in psql called `createddate` of type `TimeStamp` with time zone like `6/30/2016 12:00:00 AM`

I want to insert that data into the SQL Server column called `DateCreated` of type `datetimeoffset`. Since I am using BizTalk all the data are handled as sting so I am using the following script like

```
public string ConvertDateCreated(string dateCreated)
{
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     return DateTime.ParseExact(dateCreated, "MMddyyyy", provider).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

[image]

But it is throwing an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>
> Exception type: FormatException
>   Source: mscorlib
>   Target Site: System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles)
>
> The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occurred
>
> at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Script1.ConvertDateCreated(String dateCreated)
>   at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)
>   at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)
>   at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
>   at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results, XmlResolver documentResolver)

Comment: Have you got examples of the date strings that are returned from the original database?

Comment: It is like `6/30/2016 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: Then your format should be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: @PaulF in the original db it is like  `6/30/2016 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: You may need to modify the ParseExact format to match - as this is different to "MMddyyyy".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error converting String in to DateTime format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261113/error-converting-string-in-to-datetime-format)

Answer (score 1):

For ParseExact, your source date format should be like `"M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`.

```
public static string ConvertDateCreated(string dateCreated)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = 
         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateCreated, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", provider)
             .ToString("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format that worked for me for a timezone sql server datetimeoffset type was:

```cs
c.CreationDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(rdr["CreationDateTime"].ToString(),
                     "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

First is you need to get the datetime format of your psql datetime `"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`

Then use `DateTimeOffset` to parse your `psql datetime`

```
public static string ConvertDateCreated(string dateCreated)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider =  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateCreated, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", provider).ToString();
    }
```

To check the result, cast the output  using your sql `datetimeoffset`

```
select cast('6/30/2016 12:00:00 AM +00:00' as datetimeoffset)
```

Try .NET fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZdpLFA