# Error converting String in to DateTime format

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am trying to convert the string in to DateTime so it can be inserted in the Ms SQL Database field which is datetime datatype.

```
public  DateTime ConvertCloseDate(string closeDate)
{
 return DateTime.ParseExact(closeDate,"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss",null);
}
```

Here closeDate holds value like 7/14/0016 5:00:00 AM I need to convert in to the datetime format that Ms SQL Database will accept.

With the above code I am getting error like

```
 String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

 Exception type: FormatException
 Source: mscorlib
 Target Site: System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles)
 The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

  at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
  at System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Script1.ConvertCloseDate(String closeDate)
```

Comment: `7/14/0016 5:00:00 AM` and `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"` don't match

Comment: does that date look like it matches that pattern to you?

Comment: @PeterBruins What format specifier should I use for the date from psql database. The String closDate stores the date from field in psql db of type TimeStamp with time zone

Comment: @user4912134 none at all. PostgreSQL can return DateTime values just fine. If you return them as strings, or convert them to strings before using them, you have a bug. Post the code that loads `closeDate`

Comment: I am using biztalk so it treat all the data as string I am not converting the psql date in to string

Comment: @user4912134 as for what format to use - have you *tried* to create a format string that matches your values? Where did you find `YYYY-MM-...` ? Doesn't that page explain what these placeholders do?

Comment: @user4912134 I'm pretty sure Biztalk doesn't. However you load the data, it *doesn't* arbitrarily decide to use a US-only format. *How* do you load that data? What types did you specify for the fields? What cultures? Even if you can't specify that dates are returned as dates, and integers as integers (highly doubtful), you can specify to use the Invariant culture. The problem isn't `ParseExact`. It's how you load the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I thought the format specifier is for the datetime returned didnt know that it needs to be of closeDate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not loading the data externally BizTalk connect to the psql and I am trying to map that in to ms sql through biztalk. So before mapping I need to convert it to the type that Ms SQL will accept

Comment: @user4912134 - You shouldn't need to do that.  BizTalk can properly handle `DateTime` values when it maps.  Have you set the datatypes of the nodes in the schemas correctly?  What does the input message look like?  Is it a flat file or something?

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` class has no format property to it.  The second argument in `DateTime.ParseExact` is the format of the *input*.

I don't know enough about your input, but my best guess for the format would be 
`M/DD/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`

Once you have a `DateTime` object, you will be fine, SQL Server will accept it.

Comment: Can I just give return DateTime.ParseExact(closeDate,"o",null);

Comment: Also the string holds the date from the psql which is 7/14/0016 5:00:00 AM what format specifier should I be using for this

Comment: @user4912134 I don't know any calendar where there are 14 months. Why don't you use the *correct* format string instead of `YYYY-MM-DD...` ?

Comment: @user4912134 I am pretty sure the "o" format is for UTC, which isn't what your format is.  Use this as a guide to build your format string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use format 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.nnnnn'  This is universally accepted in SQL Server regardless of your language settings.  Any other formats may cause anomalies or errors when a system is using a different language.

Comment: @WesH That is irrelevant since he is converting a string to a DateTime object.  The problem isn't getting it into SQL right now, it is getting it out of the string format he is currently using.

Comment: @WesH there are a lot of things wrong with this comment. The format you propose is not universally accepted. The OP tried to use ISO8601 which *is* universally accepted. The problem though isn't about some date formats - DateTime doesn't have any format, it's a binary value. SQL Server accepts it just fine. No formats or strings are required. The problem is that the OP tried to parse a US date literal (ie string) using the ISO8601 format and failed

Comment: @WesH in fact, every time you hear about databases and date formats it means there is a bug. Either dates are stored as strings, or instead of data parameters someone uses string parameters, or far worse, the SQL query is constructed by concatenating strings. In that case you also have the possibility of a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - the point was that the format I mentioned is a culture/language neutral syntax for string dates in SQL Server.  Regardless of the database language settings, '20170425' will be correctly interpreted as April 25, 2017.  '2017-04-25' will be rejected by some languages as an out of range value.

However, my comment is misplaced because he is converting to a date in the application code before sending to SQL Server.  As MrZander said, my comment was not relevant.

Comment: @WesH no it's not. It's an arbitrary format. The culture neutral, product neutral, unambigurous format  in .NET is is `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` plus timezone info. The unseparated format is neutral only for dates. There are a couple of neutral [standard formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) like `s`, `o`, and `u` that can be used with `ParseExact`. SQL Server recognizes the ISO8601 format for datetime too. It's the format used for Javascript, JSON, SOAP, actually everyone.

Comment: SQL Server can parse date literals too, but if you end up parsing on the server, something is already wrong. You shouldn't store dates as strings or use date literals in client queries. That's what strongly-typed parameters are for

Answer (score -1):

Try to use TryParse to see if it is a valid datetime and if it is MS SQL will accept closedDate string as is.

```
DateTime warrantyDate;
bool recDate = DateTime.TryParse(closedDate, out warrantyDate);
if(recDate)
{
    //if rec date is true, MS SQL will accept it as datetime
}
```

Comment: Why do that? There's already an exception saying that the input doesn't match the format

Comment: He is trying to use a ParseExact, which is throwing the error. It seems that he is just trying to use a parse to convert a string to a datetime object to insert it into the database, but as long as that string is a valid date, he doesn't even have to convert the string to a datetime object, just insert the string into a datetime MS SQL field. So, just do a quick check to see if the string he has is able to be converted to a datetime object and if so, just insert the string.

Comment: The error is because the wrong format is used. There is no reason to check something else. Using TryParse isn't going to fix anything, just ignore the error. In fact, *this* particulare overload is wrong because it uses the current application's locale, which can be anything.

Comment: And finally - SQL Server accepts dates just fine. As long as you send dates  (ie DateTime objects) instead of arbitrary strings. The OP isn't asking about this, it's the *parsing* code that has a problem

Comment: I guess I am just offering an alternate way to insert a value into a database's datetime field. This is what I do to make sure the string is able to be converted to a datetime object before any insert is called.